# Assigning a variable as a marker within a function

Tags: javascript

Trying to use a variable(`var checkTrueMrk`) as a marker/state to determine an if condition.

On a button click if the '`checkTrueMrk`' variable is true then the if condition does not proceed otherwise the checkTrueMrk is set to true. However on repeat click the checkTrueMrk always starts as false.

Is it possible to use a variable this way. I know its possible with an object literal or objects from constructor functions where I can create a property or even just a global variable set outside of the function.

edit** However why does the variable default to 'false' on subsequent clicks after it has been set to true ?

**My code:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    console.log(checkTrueMrk); //undefinied
    console.log(typeof checkTrueMrk); //undefined

    if (typeof checkTrueMrk == 'undefined' || !checkTrueMrk) {
        var checkTrueMrk = false;
    }

    console.log(checkTrueMrk); //displays false and type of boolean as expected

    if(!checkTrueMrk){
        console.log("Im not true");
        checkTrueMrk = true;
        console.log("I am now set to " + checkTrueMrk 
            + "and I am type of" 
            + typeof checkTrueMrk);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned that you need variable to act as a flag but don't want it to be global. If I understood correct, below way of using a self executing anonymous function may just work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<body>    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>    
<script>    
var myFunction = (function() { 
    alert("came in");     
    var checkTrueMrk = false;   
    return function(){       
     if(!checkTrueMrk){         
       alert("I will be called once");       
       checkTrueMrk = true;      
     }   
    };    
})();  
</script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

On

> However why does the variable default to 'false' on subsequent clicks after it has been set to true ?

This is simply because in your  implementation, the variable is scoped within the function. After the function call finishes, the existence of the variables declared within is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the variable outsode the function, so it will be undefinde for the first time. Add `var checkTrueMrk = flase;` to the top of your code.

Comment: Well, he did `var checkTrueMrk = false;`

Comment: On first click the variable is undeclared therefore typeof  'undefined' in the first if condition which then declares the variable

Comment: @Yuri but inside the function and not above. He should declare it outside.

Comment: yeah it can be declare outside as well as the other ways ive mentioned however why the variable default to 'false' on subsequent clicks after it has been set to true ?

Comment: @marcel But there was nothing inside your answer pointing it should be declared outside of the function. As you have added more details I'm revoking my downvote. :)

Comment: @Yuri, i edited my answer. I did not search in the function, because i didn't expected there. :D